# Metamask does not select my Ganache network

Tags: javascript, ethereum, metamask, ganache

I have a local ganache running and I have a select field in my application where a network can be selected. Once a network is selected I'm running this code to switch to that network in metamask:

```
await ethereum.request({
  method: 'wallet_switchEthereumChain',
  params: [{ chainId: selectedChainId }],
});
```

I have added my ganache instance as network to metamask with the following information:

- Name: Ganache Local
- RPC URL: HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545 (this is what ganache shows me)
- Chain ID: 1337

Now when I select my ganache network in my application, metamask always tries to switch to the network "Localhost 8545". I think because it has the same chain id. Thats why I have deleted the "Localhost 8545" network to only have one network with the chain id 1337, but if I try it again metamask still chooses the "Localhost 8545" network, even if it does not exist anymore:

[image]

And if I confirm then no network switch is applied and I'm getting no error or something else.

Any idea how I can switch to my ganache network programmatically to test my application with ganache?

Comment: same here :( nothing happened after i approved switch network on metamask dialog